# How to check a string is symmetric or not in Swift

Tags: swift, string, palindrome

```
return value == String(value.reversed())
```

This is what I tried. It works well but takes a little bit longer. Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: this is a standard (and simple) algorithmic question to check if a string is a palindrome. There are plenty of resources out there including this one: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing available in the standard library for `String`, or for anything else, so a solution for only `String` probably isn't the best option.

You don't need to make a new instance of anything based on `reversed`; `elementsEqual` does the job.

```swift
public extension Sequence where Element: Equatable {
  var isSymmetric: Bool { elementsEqual(reversed()) }
}
```

```swift
"".isSymmetric // true
"".isSymmetric // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You could in c test each character one at a time from beginning and end until your two indices meet in the middle. But for Swift you don't have a guarantee that characters are the same length in a Swift String, they have to store strings that are made of unicode characters which can have one of 100,000's of characters at the moment, I think they currently do this by storying the String using UTF16. So you can not just use offset logic to quickly calculate the index for a character, you have to enumerate through each character, checking the length of each character to get to the next. Objective-C made this even more complicated with the potential of private subclasses of NSString, each could have different encoding methods.

Answer (score 0):

A less expensive way than reversing the array is to walk simultaneously from the beginning and the end to the middle and compare each character - or whatever the `Element` of the type conforming to `BidirectionalCollection` is.

```
public extension BidirectionalCollection where Element: Equatable {
    
  var isPalindrome: Bool {
      if isEmpty { return true }
      var  = startIndex
      var  = index(before: endIndex)
      while  <  {
          if self[] != self[] { return false }
          formIndex(after: &)
          formIndex(before: &)
      }
      return true
  }
}
```